# TapTargetView library hides Recycler View's item with outer circle color

Tags: android, android-library

I'm using TapTargetViwew to guide my end users on how to use my App.

Out of available libraries for overflow view, TapTargetView and Spotlight have got minimal issues opened and well maintained.

I choose TapTargetView over Spotlight because I can do some of the customizations with out of the box methods.

TapTargetView is working well with `ToolBar` and Rest of the static widgets.
But I need to highlight a recycler item. It's getting highlighted but it hides the entire item with outer circle color.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the outer circle color to transparent or set alpha to your outer circle color

```
TapTarget.forView(itemView,yourTitle,yourDescription)
                    .drawShadow(true)
                    .tintTarget(true)
                    .transparentTarget(true)
                    .outerCircleColor(android.R.color.transparent)//or #80000000
                    .id(yourItemId);
```

Comment: I still need my outer circle color as my primary color. I don't want to go for transparent.

Comment: You can try setting alpha to your color instead of making your entire outer circle transparent for example #FF9800 => #70FF9800

Comment: That also will set a semi-transparent background to the outer circle. But still, my centre content will carry out the same color. My problem is not color. I want my target view to be left as is.

Comment: I dont understand your requirement clearly it seems as per your question `It's getting highlighted but it hides the entire item with outer circle color.` your issue was, the outer circle color is hiding the entire item, pls be clear with your question

Comment: I want my content to be highlighted around. That's how the library is expected to work as per the screenshot on their GitHub page. https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView . I've mentioned its working fine for static views but my entire recycler item getting hidden - Ref my screenshot. Have you ever tried with recycler item?

Comment: yes i have used taptargetview with recycler view, I have created a custom holder for the itemview and created a taptargetsequence

Comment: transparentTarget(true) is what missed out.